# Html.TextBoxFor change color value if error at login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.textbox

I am new to mvc and I wonder how I can change the background color if the User do@html.TextBoxFor enter the wrong login.
I'm using it quite simply.

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {@class="caixa_login_email" })

How could add a new value for background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a [Required] attribute on the Email property, when the posted ModelState is invalid, the TextBox will have a class added to it like '.input-validation-error'

You could add a css style to change the background color:

.input-validation-error { background-color: #000; }